# Real-time video call analysis when using WebRTC

Tags: android, webrtc, firebase-mlkit, google-mlkit, webrtc-android

I use `libjingle_peerconnection` for video calls. How can I simultaneously analyze the video for face detection and smile detection?

I made some efforts and was able to get the frames from the WebRTC `SurfaceView`, but when I access a frame, the `SurfaceView` can no longer display it and the screen turns green.